# How to remove Javascript Cache?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs with i18n for translation. The problem is that I need a way to make a version because this is loading from cache every time

```
i18n/lang-en.json
```

Any clue what I can do to make the lang-xx.json with versions so I don't get a cache in this files?
They are not loading from anywhere but I think they can be fixed in my configLang.js

```
angular.module('moduleApp.config', ['xxx.ui.commons.defaults.config.lang']);

angular.module('moduleApp.config').config(['$translateProvider', '$languageSupportProvider', function($translateProvider, $languageSupportProvider){

        // add your module specific language file to the loading chain
        // $languageSupportProvider.addLanguageFileLocation('plugins/moduleApp/i18n/moduleApp-lang-:optionsKey.json', {});

    }]
);
```

Comment: you change that on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can add an hash as query string to the `TranslateHttpLoader`:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json?cb=' + new Date().getTime());
}
```

There are outher solutions in the github issue: [Cached JSON file](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader/issues/25)